# Primefaces live scrolling taking long time with large datasets

Tags: performance, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Hi I have a primefaces datatable with about 52000 records to be fetched.Since it is a large dataset,i tried using live scrolling feature of primefaces with scroll rows equal to 20.THe number of columns is 53.The table also has filtering and sorting feature on its each column.Still i am not satisfied with the performance of the table.It takes about 15 secs for the page to load,worst thing is that it takes about 65 secs for the next set of 20 records to be loaded on reaching the end of scrolling.

Just for testing i reduced the total number of records to 25000 and the preformance improves with scroll time of 29 secs.**I am really not able to understand why it is taking this much time when i am displaying only 20 records at a time.The total number of records should not have affected the performance.**

Can  someone please suggest how to improve the performance.I cannot implement pagination for this since my customer don't want it.Thanks in advance

My JSF code snippet

```
<p:dataTable id="arcRecList" var="data"
            value="#{archivedRecordBean.archiveItems}"
            tableStyle="table-layout:auto; width:80%;" styleClass="datatable"
            scrollable="true" scrollWidth="84%" scrollHeight="69%"
            columnClasses="columnwidth" liveScroll="true" scrollRows="20"
            filteredValue="#{archivedRecordBean.filteredArchiveItems}">


            <p:column style="width:250px" headerText="Insured"
                filterBy="#{data.insuredName}" sortBy="#{data.insuredName}">
                <h:outputText value="#{data.insuredName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:250px" headerText="City"
                filterBy="#{data.custAddress_City}"
                sortBy="#{data.custAddress_City}">
                <h:outputText value="#{data.custAddress_City}" />
            </p:column>
                .
                .
                .53 columns
                .
        </p:dataTable>
```

My Managed bean

@ManagedBean

@RequestScoped

public class ArchivedRecordBean implements Serializable {

```
private List<WorkSpaceItem> archiveItems=null;
private List<WorkSpaceItem>filteredArchiveItems;
private WorkSpaceItem objWorkSpaceItem=null;
JdbcConnection jdbcConnection=null;
Connection connection=null;
Statement selectStmt=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
public ArchivedRecordBean()

{   
    getArchiveFields();

}
public List<WorkSpaceItem> getArchiveItems() {
    return archiveItems;
}
public void setArchiveItems(List<WorkSpaceItem> archiveItems) {
    this.archiveItems = archiveItems;
}
public WorkSpaceItem getObjWorkSpaceItem() {
    return objWorkSpaceItem;
}
public void setObjWorkSpaceItem(WorkSpaceItem objWorkSpaceItem) {
    this.objWorkSpaceItem = objWorkSpaceItem;
}

public List<WorkSpaceItem> getFilteredArchiveItems() {
    return filteredArchiveItems;
}
public void setFilteredArchiveItems(List<WorkSpaceItem> filteredArchiveItems) {
    this.filteredArchiveItems = filteredArchiveItems;
}
public void getArchiveFields()
{
    try
    {
        jdbcConnection=new JdbcConnection();
        connection=jdbcConnection.getJdbcConnection();
        selectStmt=connection.createStatement();
        String query="select * from LPINFO where LPINFO.ClearDate < (select TOP 1 Tbl_CurrentYear.CurrentYear from dbo.Tbl_CurrentYear)"
                +"AND (LPINFO.ClearDate is not null)";
        rs=selectStmt.executeQuery(query);
        archiveItems=new ArrayList<WorkSpaceItem>();
        while(rs.next())
        {

            objWorkSpaceItem=new WorkSpaceItem();
            objWorkSpaceItem.setInsuredName(rs.getString("InsuredName"));
            objWorkSpaceItem.setCustAddress_City(rs.getString("CustAddress_City"));
            objWorkSpaceItem.setCustAddress_State(rs.getString("CustAddress_State"));
            .
            .
            .//Setting the values for remaining columns
            .
            .
            archiveItems.add(objWorkSpaceItem);

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {

            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the managed bean to @ViewScoped. I can`t do a test right now, but as far as I know the a requestScoped bean is created on each HTTP request, so I think the problem might be that you are querying the data base on each scroll. That would explain why the load time decreases with less records on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I takes so long because you are **loading all items from the database**, on every request (@RequestScope bean are recreated on every request).

If you change to @ViewScope, you will load the data only once, but they will all be stored in session, slowing down you server. If you are saving state in client, it would have gigantic impact on network usage, and very big CPU usage because of serializing/deserializng. Not a good idea either.

You should, as minimum, implement [LazyDataModel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf), and always limit the amount of data that is read from database (giving >1000 pages for end user makes no sense from UX view).

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for your reply.Is it really worth to use LazyDataModel with live scrolling.What i got to know is it is of no use with live scolling according to one of the responses in the primefaces forum [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20772)